# Число сочетаний определенного числа слагаемых - сумма, которых равна N

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

Для Q числа слагаемых найти число всевозможных сочетаний, сумма слагаемых должна быть равна числу N.
Т.е. пример. для количества слагаемых 3 - нужно найти число сочетаний(не перестановки), когда сумма равна 9.
И так для любого Q,N.
(0,0,9 | 0,1,8 и т.п. - примеры сочетаний)
Не полным перебором.

Comment: Открываете Кнута, *Искусство программирования*, том 4А, стр. 447, и смотрите Алгоритм H - разбиение числа N на M частей...

Comment: Так вам нужно **найти всевозможные сочетания** - именно сами сочетания, или их количество (**нужно найти число сочетаний**)? Вы понимаете, что это совершенно разные задачи? Какую из них вы не в состоянии решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, науке неизвестна закрытая (нерекуррентная) формула для решения этой задачи. Поэтому придется строить рекуррентную формулу.

Пусть `P(n, q)` - искомое количество разложений числа `n` на `q` слагаемых. Для того, чтобы обеспечить уникальность сумм, будем считать только *упорядоченные* суммы, в которых слагаемые *не убывают*. Ясно, что если первое слагаемое суммы больше чем `[n/q]`, то такую упорядоченную сумму построить невозможно.

Введем вспомогательную функцию `Q(n, q, s)` - это количество разбиений числа `n` на суммы `q` неубывающих слагаемых, в которых первое слагаемое (а, следовательно, и все остальные) не меньше `s`. Тогда

Q(n, q, s) = Σ<sub>a = s...[n/q]</sub> Q(n - a, q - 1, a)

В качестве базы рекурсии имеем

Q(n, 1, a) = 1
      Q(0, q, a) = 1

И тогда, разумеется, искомое

P(n, q) = Q(n, q, 0)

Далее пишем программу, возможно (лучше) с [мемоизацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) промежуточных рекуррентных решений.

Хотя, если обратить внимание на тот факт, что база рекурсии состоит только из значений `1`, мы фактически выполняем целенаправленный рекурсивный перебор всех возможных решений. Не знаю, этот перебор вы имели в виду под вашим "НЕ ПЕРЕБОРОМ", или какой-то более страшный. Но в этом решении сделать перебор менее "переборным" может только мемоизация.